# How to reinstall without losing any data

Tags: server

I also need to know How do I reinstall ubuntu without losing any data? I am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. And I need to keep eveything installed, my website, MySQL databases everything.

Comment: Consider reversing the order of your question: How to backup, then how to reinstall. Without good backups, a reinstall is risky. Also, the way your question is phrased implies that you have some kind of problem, and that you think reinstalling is the preferred solution ([XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)). Consider asking about the original problem instead.

Comment: Ok,  I will edit it,

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: I have backed up all my data that I need to keep

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB installer and follow the prompts.

Comment: Doesn't that just wipe eveything?, I have backups, but I have other stuff that I cannot back up that I would like to try to save, so wiping is a last resort

Comment: It will give your the option to wipe, or to overwrite without wiping. The latter work if 1) Your filesystem is undamaged, and 2) Your customizations are compatible with 20.04. Me, I keep notes on how to rebuild every system from scratch...including reinstalling all customizations. Only needed those notes once in 10 years, but really, really glad I had them that day -- saved many days of pain.

Comment: ok I can try that in about 20mins