# Server Install error 404 not found during ubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

I get disco no longer has a release file. How do I fix this? 
The error I get is

```
Err:9 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39.80]
Err:10 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39.80]
Err:11 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39.80]
Error:12 https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
   404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39.80]
Reading Package lists...
E: The repository 'https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file
E: The repository 'https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file
E: The repository 'https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file
E: The repository 'https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file
E: The repository 'https://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file
```

It has more but I do not think that it is important if you want me to
include it just ask I will.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: No, I have to install the OS

Comment: As already mentioned by Pizza in their answer, 19.04 reached End of Public support in January 2020. All the archives of Disco have been moved to old-releases. Consider editing sources.list as instructed by the top answer of the above question and upgrade to 19.10. From 19.10, you can upgrade to 20.04.

Comment: Here you say you have 20.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239171/how-to-reinstall-without-losing-any-data Are these different PCs?

Comment: I had to reinstall

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your issue is 'disco' (19.04) is EOL.  After a release goes EOL, mirrors can drop it, and the main archive.ubuntu.com gets moved to old-releases.  Refer to prior comment and EOLUpgrades link, or https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a repository / install from a repository of disco dingo (ubuntu 19.04). That version has reached its end of life and no longer supported. That is why that repo no longer has release files.

The version you should use (if you're still interested in 19.x versions) is ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine), but you should also take in mind that this version will not be supported for much longer.

Also, about the versions you mentioned: ubuntu 18.2 does not exist, ubuntu 22.04 release is planned to April 2022). Ubuntu 20.04 is currently the latest release.

For more information: [Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/),
[Eoan Ermine Release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes),
[The Ubuntu lifecycle and release cadence](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle)

Comment: So how do I install Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Download an iso from here: [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/)

Comment: How do I make a bootable USB drive on a mac? I know Etcher dose not work

Comment: Download the iso and create a bootable cd, just like you have with ubuntu 19.04. You can also  create a bootable usb flash drive, or any other method you / your organisation know about for installing ubuntu os. That is the easiest and shortest way to do so. @Kulfy offered another way of doing so at the comments to your question, and this is usefull if you have no other means of installations at all. This might help you: [BurningIsoHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto), [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: Added a link in my comment :)

Comment: Minor corrections needed I think sorry; Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't exist yet, s/much long/much longer/ maybe, I'd also point to release notes for 19.10 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes) but I like links

Comment: Thank you, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case if you do not have a PC and iso with supported ubuntu version, than install the current version unchecking **Download updates while installing Ubuntu**

[image]

Then you could download 20.04, write your installation medium with it and reinstall Ubuntu using it.

It is better to reinstall it, than upgrade from unsupported release.

Use the next command to replace some names in deprecated repositories records (if you want to install something with apt before reinstalling):

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The command replaces `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You could do it with `nano` by hand. Then `sudo apt update` and so on.

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/925971)

Comment: I do not have anything installed,

Comment: I don't have a OS installed yet

Comment: I am trying to install ubuntu server

Comment: I am using a flash drive installed with Rufus, I THINK it is working now